# How to resolve "application executable is missing a required architecture" error with MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

We're not currently using the LLVM compiler at the moment.  What I'm finding is that if I compile with "Minimum OS Version" set to 4.0, the Application Loader returns an error saying:
iPhone/IPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7

I noticed that this happened before the last release of MonoTouch as well...but at that time, the LLVM compiler was working for my project, and the error didn't occur with LLVM.  It is almost as if the introduction of the LLVM compiler caused the "old" compilation method to stop marking executables with an architecture somehow.

Has anyone seen this or worked around it?  I tried adding "armv7" to the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in plist file (based on other reading) but that doesn't resolve the issue.

All is well with Application Loader if I set "Minimum OS Version" to 3.0, but the resulting .IPA is huge.

Comment: If you are not using LLVM then mono AOT compiler will produce an ARMv6 binary. Maybe some other settings are implying that you wish to publish an ARMv7 binary ?

Comment: It seems like perhaps setting your minimum OS version to 4.0 implies that you will be supplying an ARMv7 binary, but then I'd be surprised if I was the first to run into this.

Comment: Actually, setting minimum OS to 3.2 has same error.  Only setting minimum OS to 3.0 avoids this error...

Answer (score 2):

I was previously using the 1.3 workaround, but after a recent OS upgrade, application loader 1.3 refused to work.

I downloaded the current version of application loader from iTunes Connect and ran right back into the arm7 required error.

After poking around a bit, I figured out that you now have to use the LVVM compiler (in iPhone Build Options, Advanced tab) and then select either `ARM6 + ARM7` or `ARM7` from the dropdown list.

After doing this, you should be able to use the new application loader.

Answer (score 1):

According to "[Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html)" the "MinimumOSVersion" key should not be used - at least not directly in the Info.plist.

> Do not specify this key yourself in the Info.plist file; it is a system-written key.

I'm not sure if this is only XCode related or if MonoDevelop does something similar (based on the SDK and deployment target you specified) but maybe you're ending up with conflicting properties ?!?

Comment: I'm not actually putting this in info.plist - I'm just using the MonoDevelop project setting to specify Minimum OS.

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly the same issue and the problem was Application Loader itself. The latest version refused to upload the binary with the error you mentioned.
Then I downgraded to Application Loader 1.3 and voila, I was able to upload again.
You can find Application Loader 1.3 here: http://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_1.3.dmg

Comment: Thanks much - I'll give this a try the next time I experience the problem.  As it happens, I seem to have landed on a combination of settings that work - but I *swear* it was a combination I've tried in the past without success.

Comment: ApplicationLoader_1.3.dmg no longer exists on Apple's site, so this solution no longer works.

Comment: I do not have any issues with the latest app loader, so the fix is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

1) Left-click project icon (blue icon, under "Run" button).

2) Next to the project icon (to the right of it), left-click on project name under "PROJECT" (White background).

3)Select tab "Build Settings" and look for tab "Build Active Architecture Only" -----change to -----no