# Application Loader refuses to upload MonoTouch application

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, application-loader

Even after reading several posts I still can't upload my application. The error message is

> iPad: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7

I have followed other questions' answers including editing the info.plist file but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I stated in other comments and answers: try using another version of Application Loader. This solved the issue for me.

See my answer here:
[How to resolve "application executable is missing a required architecture" error with MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070469/how-to-resolve-application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture-error/7118419#7118419)

And the download link for App Loader 1.3 here:
http://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_1.3.dmg

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a solution which would make sense to me but whatever works...

Comment: Yes @Krumelur it (strangely) does.